# Upgrade ASP.NET 3.5 32 bit Website to 64 Bit

Tags: asp.net, 64-bit, 32-bit

We have a website that was created in VS 2008 and it is 32 bit compatible. What are the steps should we take to make it a 64 bit application.

This is what I have followed:
1. Create a new ASP.NET Empty Web Application Project in VS 2017 with .NET Framework 4.6.1
2. Added a new Configuration for 64 bit by copying the settings from Any CPU
[image: Confiuration of 64 Bit]
3. Copied all the files and folders from my old ASP.NET Website to this newly created project.

Result:
Compilation: Fine
We are using ReportViewer. But when we try to open the report we are getting HTTP 404 - Not Found error for Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd. We do have an handler registered for it in web.config file.

Can anybody point us in the right direction to upgrade our old 3.5 ASP.NET Website App to be 64 bit compatible.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do anything except to make sure that the build setting is set to "Any CPU". By setting it to "AnyCPU" the application will JIT to 64 bit code when loaded into 64 bit process and 32 bit when loaded into a 32 bit process.  And this is true even for the application in VS2008.  So if your project in VS2008 was set to AnyCPU, it already was running as 64-bit application if run on 64-bit machine.

---

I think your issue might be because you are updating the project to .Net 4.5.1 and using the ReportViewer. When you moved the code over did you update to the latest version of ReportViewer.  If not, try doing that and see if that takes care of the issue.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Report.Viewer

You also will probably want to install the following extension so you can edit your ".rldc" reports.

"Microsoft Rdlc Report Designer for Visual Studio"

Also, make sure the web.config entries are update to the latest version as well.

Comment: No I did not update ReportViewer. I will install the extension and update report viewer too. Thanks :)

Comment: I have added ```<add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>``` to web.config file. Now it's throwing ReportViewer ambiguous in namespace Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms. In .aspx tagprefix is registered like ```<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
    Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>```

Comment: I also added ```<add name="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>``` to web.config file. Here name attribute is not allowed.

Comment: Change the version numer of the tagprefix in the aspx page.  It is still  set to "Version=8.0.0.0".  Let me know if this took care of the issue and if you have any other errors come up.

Comment: Yes I did not copy paste the old web.config file instead pasted all the required sections and added the above entries and now Reports are working as usual. Thanks.

Comment: SureI will. Thanks again 